# Loading dynamic model attributes in the form - django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So I'm building an Ads app. 
Basically, users log in, and they can post an ad for something.
I've posted the models below but basically I have a category (say, electronics or real estate), then a subcategory(electronics->Laptop or real estate-> house,apartment etc.)
The problem is, different items have different attributes.
For example, a Laptop might have "screen", "ram" and "hdd" attributes, while a "Car" might have "mileage" and "condition". 
I decided to store these attributes in a JSONField.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    price_fixed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    monthly_payments = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    custom_attributes = JSONField(default=dict)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Now, how do I handle these custom attributes in the form and the views?
I need to make it so that when the user selects a category/subcategory from a dropdown, these attributes need to appear as text fields and the user would enter screen size, t-shirt size or color etc.

This is my first django app, and the book I learned from didn't cover things like this and I'm not exactly sure where to go from here, searching on google/SO didn't find me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONFields are good for structured metadata that Python won't introspect very often.

In your case I would suggest creating another table for field configuration, link this table to category and have a table for values in products. In a simplified form:

```
class CategoryAtrribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value_type = models.CharField()


class Category(models.Model):
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryAtrribute)


class AttributeValues(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('CategoryAtrribute')
    value = models.TextField()


class Product(models.Model):
    attribute_values = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryAtrribute, through=AttributeValues)
```

The problems here are basically two:
 1. You need to ensure that product will have only attributes allowed by its category
 2. Functions checking types of fields need to be hardcoded

A simplier version of this solution is to create a table Metadata with all possible fields for all categories. This model will have one2one with product and Category will have list of fields to use from it.

Comment: What kind of data is supposed to go in value_type ?

Comment: Type of the value stored in this field - string, int, etc.

Comment: It is only important if you want to do simething with this value (e.g. check which car is the heaviest). If you only want to store/filter by this values you can deal without `value_type`

Comment: Took me a while but I think I got it (the whole solution) :)
Is there a way to access the attribute value from the product class?
Right now I can access the value like this: >>> AttributeValues.objects.get(product=p1), where p1 is a Product object.

Comment: As I see now there is an error in `AttributeValues` class. It should be:
`product = models.ForeignKey('Product')` instead of category. You can access values from products with this: `product.attributevalues_set`.

Comment: Thats awesome thank you so much. If someone interest how to filter on product just like this. After get attributes from category. as a1 and a2 then you can filter like Product.objects.filter(attributevalues__attribute=a1, attributevalues__value="Intel Core i7").filter(attributevalues__attribute=a2, attrib
utevalues__value="red")